# Know all the views presented on a view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am facing a problem where I have multiple views presented at a particular time. Now if my app get timed out and I have to get back to Login Screen, I am able to pop all view controllers from the navigation stack but how to Know how many view controllers are presented at that particular moment so that I can dismiss all of them.

Answer (score 0):

navigationController.viewControllers would return the current view controller stack. try that.

Comment: I believe this works only for controllers that are pushed on to the navigation stack . Here I am presenting multiple View controllers.